# Proper locking model for synchronous, thread safe interface

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I am designing a small library as part of a toy project. Simplified, it would be something like:

```
class FoobarManager {
    public:
        // Creates a new Foobar object internally an returns its ID
        int createNewFoobar();

        // Makes the Foobar object identified by foobarId frobnicate
        void frobnicate(int foobarId);

        // Removes the internal Foobar object identified by foobarId
        void removeFoobar(int foobarId);

    private:
        // ID - Foobar
        std::map<int, Foobar> allFoobars;
};
```

The idea is that I can have several `Foobar` at the same time, each of them will have an ID that I can use to ask FoobarManager to manipulate them. My goal is to make the library:

1. Thread safe: not making any assumption about what thread each method is called from.
2. Synchronous: I want `createNewFoobar()` to return a `Foobar`, not provide a `onFoobarCreated()` callback.
3. As independent as possible from the point of view of different `Foobar` objects: don't lock all `Foobar` objects when one is frobnicating.

I can't seem to find a good locking model to fulfill all of them. I guess I need at least a `mutex` per `Foobar`, and another `mutex` to control insertion/deletion in the map.

Getting insertion of new objects work along with `frobnicate` seems easy:

```
int createNewFoobar() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mapLock(mapMutex);
    allFoobars[++nextId] = Foobar();
    return nextId;
}

void frobnicate(int foobarId) {
    // Not using lock_guard because we need to intertwine with another lock
    mapMutex.lock();
    if (allFoobars.count(foobarId) == 0) return;
    Foobar& fb = allFoobars.at(foobarId);
    // Lock on the Foobar mutex
    // ...
    mapMutex.unlock();
    fb.frobnicate();
    // Unlock the Foobar mutex
    // ...
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to get rid of a certain `Foobar` in the map (and its mutex) without invalidating references to it from `frobnicate()`. Is there a way of achieving this?

I have considered serializing all the calls into a message queue and use asynchronous callbacks internally, using blocking waits to appear synchronous from the outside. That would be thread safe and appear synchronous, but would not fulfill point 3.

Comment: Because you are incrementing nextId and writing to allFoobars only from createNewFoobar and not in frobnicate, you could test for foobarId <= nextId and increment nextId (like you actually do) right after you inserted Foobar. So you wouldn't need the mutex. You also should mark nextId as atomic then. You would only need the mutx in createNewFoobar if you invoke createNewFoobar from multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a type when transcribing the insertion method. `nextId` is not the problem, the problem is how to delete without knowing if another thread is holding a reference to the object you are about to delete while at the same time not locking all other Foobars.

Comment: You may use std::shared_ptr and implicitly pass the ownership to the thread holding the reference. After the thread finished, the object would be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing a shared pointer to Foobar in the map, you can safely remove it while frobnicate is working on it.

The map:

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Foobar> > allFoobars;
```

The code

```
int createNewFoobar() {
    // First create the Foobar, so a lengthy creation does not hold the mutex
    std::shared_ptr<Foobar> newFoobar(std::make_shared<Foobar>());

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mapLock(mapMutex);
    allFoobars[nextId] = newFoobar;
    return nextId++;
}

void frobnicate(int foobarId) {
    std::map<Foobar>::iterator findFoobar;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mapLock(mapMutex);
        findFoobar = allFobars.find(foobarId);
        if (findFoobar == allFoobar.end())
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    findFoobar.second->frobnicate();
}
```

Then even if you remove the Foobar from the map, the shared pointer in `findFoobar.second` is still keeping it alive until `frobnicate` terminates.